# How to setup network setting on virtual box so that i can do ssh - mac os

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I am setting up a virtual machine via virtual box and after setting it up with an installed ubuntu. I want to be able to ssh on the my machine. I don't know which network setting to use.

I tried to change the adapter1 from NAT to Bridge Adapter, but after doing that I couldn't start my vm disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the VirtualBox settings press network, then adapter 1. Select NAT, then press advanced. Here you can press Port Forwarding and you can add a new port forwarding rule. The default for SSH is 22. I would suggest using localhost IP (127.0.1.1) on for example port 2222 and then you can ssh using the command.

Just to be clear port forward setup:

name 'port-fwd', protocol TCP, host IP 127.0.0.1 host port 2222 guest IP 10.0.2.15 guest port 22. Then you can run:

```
ssh -p 2222 user@127.0.0.1
```